# Can't install electron because of permission error

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I can't install electron via npm.
I try to execute with sudo but same error arose.
Also tried official method (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) but it didn't fix this problem.

os: Ubuntu 16.04
node version: 8.5.0
npm version: 5.4.2

I install electron 1.7.6 because latest version(1.7.8) has no Linux package.

> npm install electron@1.7.6
>
> electron@1.7.6 postinstall
>   /home/tombo/workspace/hatebu-viewer-client/node_modules/electron node
>   install.js
>
> /home/tombo/workspace/hatebu-viewer-client/node_modules/electron/install.js:48
>         throw err
>         ^
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, link
>   '/tmp/electron-tmp-download-9437-1506349033474/electron-v1.7.6-linux-x64.zip'
>   -> '/home/tombo/.electron/electron-v1.7.6-linux-x64.zip'
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! electron@1.7.6
>   postinstall: node install.js npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
>   Failed at the electron@1.7.6 postinstall script. npm ERR!

This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Could anyone solve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: run it with sudo... sudo npm install electron@1.7.6.. does that help?

Comment: Yes, It works... I make mistake but other problem arose. I try to fix by myself  for a while, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not have to specify the version of electron. Instead you can just install it globally first by using this command:

```
$ sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true
```

And then init your project with command:

```
$ npm init
$ npm install electron --save
```

The global installation is necessary to run your app with comman `$ electron .`.